# Accessing data from EF .sdf file and no edmx designer contents

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, entity

I don't know if I created Entity, but an `EDMX` file is created at my solution. It has no tables, because, I created a new one and then the database with table and data (`.SDF` file). I want to retrieve data from table now.

First problem is, I do not know how to drag and drop it so that EDMX designer is not empty.

Second and most important is, I get an error in the below code, it says, "}" expect, but I do not see any error as you can see.

Genius people, please don't point that, there is no return from function, it is because, I am unable to type "return' inside the function - Strange. It says, it is not permitted inside class/struct.

```
namespace Waf.BookLibrary.Library.Applications.Services
{
    class Service
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Student> GetAllStudents()
        {
        private ObservableCollection<Student> studentsList;

        public StudentEntities StudentEntities { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
        {
            get
            {
                if (studentsList == null && StudentEntities != null)
                {
                    StudentEntities.Set<Student>().Load();
                    studentsList = StudentEntities.Set<Student>().Local;
                }

                return studentsList;
            }
        }

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I have put the code right from namespace, but its not showing here due to perhaps some alignment problem. So experts, please do not point that out. Thank you

Comment: It's not in good taste to name your variable exactly the same as your class (StudentEntities StudentEntities). The compiler might not like it either.

Comment: You don't drag and drop tables into an edmx. Choose the "update model from database" command.

Comment: @supertopi: Are you confident that it is the problem? In other solution from internet, it works.

Comment: @GertArnold: Thank you I did, now what to do next?

Comment: @GertArnold: Thank you and sorry, but it shows me some "{" expected error still, any clue at all? Why none of the experts also is not able to find the problem here :( So sad I am :(

Comment: @GertArnold: I didn't get you. I shown you the code as in VS and I shown you the error, what more do you expect? I get this simple error and where is the simple solution? What more do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is easily overlooked because it's quite unexpected. You can't define properties etc. *inside* a method. This is what the structure should be:

```
class Service
{
    private ObservableCollection<Student> studentsList;

    public StudentEntities StudentEntities { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get
        {
            if (studentsList == null && StudentEntities != null)
            {
                StudentEntities.Set<Student>().Load();
                studentsList = StudentEntities.Set<Student>().Local;
            }

            return studentsList;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Student> GetAllStudents()
    {
        // Code here
    }   
}
```

Comment: THank you so much Gert, I was so silly, but till date never knew we can't declare property inside the method. Thank you again for this.